# Multiple Case Statements return Different Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, case, multiple-columns

Problem: I am doing multiple case statments, however it returns only as one column. I would like multiple columns returned.

Current Code

```
declare @currentweek as nvarchar(10)
declare @1stweek as nvarchar(10)
declare @2ndweek as nvarchar(10)

set @currentweek= convert(varchar(10),dateadd(ww,0,GETDATE()),110)
set @1stweek= convert(varchar(10),dateadd(ww,1,GETDATE()),110)


select
case 
 when [date] < @currentweek then 'R' 
 when [date] > @currentweek and [date]<@1stweek then 'R' 
else null 
end [current week],[first week]
```

What I am trying to see is multiple columns. If the condition is met then the value R will be placed in either the [first week] or [current week] column.

Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't declare your date variables as `NVarchar`.  Leave them as `Date` or `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two different `Case` statements - one for each column:

```
select  case    when [date] < @currentweek  then 'R' 
                else null   
                end as [current week],
        case    when [date] > @currentweek 
                    and [date] < @1stweek   then 'R' 
                else null   
                end as [first week]
```